# 3D Plot ROS Message geometry_msgs/Posestamped with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, ros, virtual-reality, pose

How can I 3D plot "geometry_msgs/Posestamped" waypoint with Matplotlib (or with any other method)? I am trying to plot the waypoint of the HTC VIVE's controllers.

I have tried to subscribe to the message and tried to extract x, y and z position and plot it with Matplotlib but it does not seem to work.

```
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose, PoseStamped
from std_msgs.msg import Float32
import rospy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
Class DataVive:

      def __init__(self):
            self.right = []
            self.trigger = Float32()
            
            self.sub_right = [rospy.Subscriber("/vive/right/pose", PoseStamped, self.rightCallback, queue_size=1)]
            self.sub_trigger = [[rospy.Subscriber("/vive/right/trigger", Float32, self.triggerCallback, queue_size=1)]

      def rightCallback(self,msg):
            self.right.append(msg)
            if len(self.right) > 1000:
                self.right = self.right[len(self.right)-1000:]
     
      def triggerCallback(self,msg):
            self.trigger = msg

if __name__ == "__main__":
      rospy.init_node("trajectory_plot")
      path = DataVive()
      vive_trajectory = path.right
      trigger_pressed = path.trigger
      while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            for i in range(len(vive_trajectory)):
                x = vive_trajectory[i].pose.position.x
                y = vive_trajectory[i].pose.position.y
                z = vive_trajectory[i].pose.position.z
                
                x_ =[]
                y_ =[]
                z_ =[]
                x_.append(x)
                y_.append(y)
                z_.append(z)
                if trigger_pressed.data > 0.99:
                      ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')
                      ax.plot(x_, y_, z_, zdir='z', label='curve in (x, y)')
                      ax.legend()
                      ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
                      ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
                      ax.set_zlim(0, 1)
                      ax.set_xlabel('X')
                      ax.set_ylabel('Y')
                      ax.set_zlabel('Z')
                      ax.view_init(elev=20., azim=-35)
                      if trigger_pressed.data < 0.99

                         plt.show()
                         break
```

This is the Posestamped message from my vr_publisher

[image]

Do my methods have any mistakes (I am a newbie with matplotlib)? I would love to plot a line of the trajectory from the Posestamped message.